# Добавление нового значения через TEdit (Не DBEdit!) c помощью связи Master-Detail

Tags: sql, база-данных, delphi, delphi-7, insert

Всем доброго дня. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть две таблицы (Страна, город), взаимосвязь между ними осуществляется с помощью Master-Detail, и всё работает отлично. Проблема заключается при добавлении нового города (через TEdit), которого нет в таблице. Если с добавление новой страны не требуется наличия внешнего ключа, то в случае с добавлением города он требуется. С DBEdit'ом получается добавить таким образом данные, так как он внешний ключ города автоматически привязывает к стране, но как прописать это с обычным TEdit'ом, что нужно прописать здесь, чтобы он добавлял также ключ от выбранной страны?

```
 begin
  Form4.Query_City.Insert; // не выполняется: ошибка "Field 'ID' cannot be modified."
  Form4.Query_City.FieldByName('ГОРОД').AsString := Form5.Edit1.Text;
  Form4.Query_City.Open;
  Form4.Query_City.Post;
```

Код выше работает с добавлением новой страны, которой нет в списке, но не работает с городом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if Query_Country.Locate('СТРАНА', [Edit_Counrty.text]) then
begin
  // Датасет Query_Country спозиционирован на строку из Edit_Counrty
  // Можно использовать Query_Country.FieldByName('ID')
end
else
begin
  // Не нашил нужную страну.
  // Добавить или сообщить об ошибке
end
```